# how to generate url in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, bootstrap-4

I would like to know how to generate url for different languages in javascript.

server sends json data to frontend, I have header file and helper function to generate url in javascript .

How to use server sending object as parameter in redirect function and generate url as

```
www.xyx.com/en/lian-xi-wo-men 
www.xyz.com/en/guan-yu-wo-men
```

```
server.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
var obj ={
"contact" : "lian-xi-wo-men", 
"url" : {"aboutus" : "guan-yu-wo-men"}
}
       res.render('index.ejs',{lang: JSON.stringify(obj)} );
})

tried <a class="nav-link" href="/<%= lang.url.aboutus  %>">About Us</a> // getting error as aboutus not defined.

header.ejs

 <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:" onclick="redirect('about-us')">About Us</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="javascript:" onclick="redirect('contact')">Contact Us</a>


helper.js
function redirect(path){
    var urlpath = window.location.origin+"/"+en+"/"+path;
    window.location.href = urlpath;
}
```

Comment: can you please clarify your question?

Comment: @Hackbyrd thanks for reply, I would like to pass sever object to redirect function, so if path is `www.xyx.com/en/contact` should generate `www.xyx.com/en/lian-xi-wo-men `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are approaching the problem entirely wrong. You don't need javascript at all. Just use the a tag href to perform what you want

```
server.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
var obj ={
"contact" : "lian-xi-wo-men", 
"url" : {"aboutus" : "guan-yu-wo-men"}
}
       res.render('index.ejs',{lang: JSON.stringify(obj)} );
})


header.ejs
// tried this not working
<a class="nav-link" href="/en/<%= lang.url.aboutus %>">About Us</a> //not working
//
<a class="nav-link" href="/en/<%= aboutus %>">About Us</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="/en/<%= contact %>">Contact Us</a>
```

---

If you really want to pass a server-side object. This is the common approach to do it.

1. Embed your server-side variable/object in the HTML by attaching it to a hidden input value. Also, don't forget to stringify it.
2. In your javascript, grab that input value, parse it back into an object and now you are able to use it in your javascript code!

```
<html>
  <input id="lang-input" type="hidden" value="<%= JSON.stringify(lang) %>">

  <!-- Include JQUERY -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // wait for HTML to fully load
    $(function() {
      // grab lang variable
      var lang = JSON.parse($('#lang-input').val());

      // now you have lang object and can do whatver you want!
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but updated my code, getting error as not defined, can you please help,

Comment: have a function to generate url since am using multiple languages so it will be `/en/about /zh/lian-xi-wo-men` , can you please suggest how to pass serverside obj to javascript function

Comment: sorry I updated it. I forgot to prepend the "/en/" to the href.

Comment: just added how to add the server-side obj to the javascript.

Comment: thanks for reply, but have updated my code (object), in that case receiving not defined error, please help

Comment: res.render('index.ejs',{lang: JSON.stringify(obj)} ); you need to remove the stringify here. When you stringify it is, it becomes a string. But you are using it as an object in your HTML code.